# EF 5 derived class with different key name

Tags: inheritance, frameworks, entity

I have the following situation in EF database first:

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        /* other properties */
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        [Key]
        public int DerivedId {get;set;}
        /* other properties */
    }
```

In this moment, the code above is not working, since I try to unmap Id property, declaring DerivedId as a key. There is a solution to do that? I know that the best solution is to rename DerivedId column to Id in database, but I cannot do that, since the database already exists from a third party and cannot be modified.

If I'm not wrong, this approach is missing in EF 4.x, I post this hoping that it was implemented in 5.0 with .NET 4.5.

Thanks,
Lixi

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create a new property that's referencing the Id in your base class?

```
[NotMapped]
public int DerivedId
{
    get { return Id; }
    set { Id = value; }
}
```